# Can't Retrieve Exact Result with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have three tables with the following structures:

**User Table**

```
UserID  Name  Age
------  ----  ---
   001    AA   23
   002    BB   25
   003    CC   30
   004    DD   24
   005    EE   23
```

**temp_User Table**

```
UserID  Name  Age
------  ----  ---
   001    AA   23
   002    BB   25
   004    DD   24
   005    EE   23
   007    GG   23
   009    HH   28
```

**ExceptionUsers Table**

```
UserID  Status
------  --------
   021    Active
   002  Inactive
   004    Active
   010    Active
   012  Inactive
```

I used the following query to retrieve my result:

**Query**

```
select
     A.Name
    ,B.Name
    ,A.Age
    ,B.Age
from User A 
inner join temp_User B
    on A.UserID = B.UserID
left join ExceptionUsers C
    on A.UserID = C.UserID
    and C.Status = 'Inactive'
order by
    A.Name
```

**Result**

```
001  AA  23
002  BB  25
005  EE  23
```

But the result includes users who are 'Active'.

```
001  AA  23
002  BB  25
004  DD  24
005  EE  23
```

How can I try the query to get my result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd move the LEFT JOIN logic to the WHERE clause, to a NOT EXISTS.

```
select A.Name, B.Name, A.Age, B.Age
from User A 
inner join temp_User B
on A.UserID = B.UserID
where not exists (select * from ExceptionUsers C
                  where A.UserID = C.UserID
                  and C.Status = 'active')
order by A.Name
```

Comment: Thanks @jarlh for helping me, your query works for my expected result

Answer (score 1):

Move C.Status = 'Inactive' to the where clause.

Comment: Which makes the OUTER JOIN a regular INNER JOIN. What's the expected result if not all users are in the table C?

Comment: thanks for your comment @idstam, my expected result is 
- **001, 'AA', 23**
- **002, 'BB', 25**
- **005, 'EE', 23**

Answer (score 0):

`Left join` does not filter the data provided on joining condition.

So you may move the joining condition `and C.Status = 'Inactive'` to where clause and it treats as `inner join`

```
select A.Name, B.Name, A.Age, B.Age
from User A 
inner join temp_User B
on A.UserID = B.UserID
left join ExceptionUsers C
on A.UserID = C.UserID
where
C.Status = 'Inactive'
order by A.Name
```

Comment: thanks @AbhikChakraborty for helping me, it doesn't come out my expected result. it only retrieve data from ExceptionUsers which is 'Inactive' status.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below query to get the list of active user with their details.

```
select * from temp_User where UserID in (select UserID from ExceptionUsers where Status = 'Inactive')
```

Comment: thanks @MoshinHilalKondkari for helping me, but it doesn't work for my expected result